# How to observe state of related object in model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I observe the state of the Session object for changes from my movie model? I need that method for determining if the current user is authenticated and the owner of each movie in order to allow editing. Property works but doesn't react to changes in the Session object. Observes won't work for now with an if clause in the handlebars template.

Code so far:

```
App.Movie = Ember.Model.extend({
  title: Ember.attr(),
  year: Ember.attr(),

  owner: Ember.belongsTo('App.User', {
    key: 'owner',
    serializer: UserType
  }),

  canEdit: function() {
    var owner = this.get('owner');

    console.log(owner, App.Session.objectId, owner.get('objectId'));

    if (owner && App.Session.objectId === owner.get('objectId')) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }.property('App.Session.objectId', 'owner')
  // }.observes('App.Session.objectId', 'owner')
});

{{#each movie in this}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{movie.year}}</td>
    <td>{{movie.title}}</td>
      {{#if movie.canEdit}}
        <td>
          <span class="clickable glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" {{action "doDeleteMovie" movie}}></span>
          <span class="clickable glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right" {{action "doUpdateMovie" movie}}></span>
        </td>
      {{else}}
        <td>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right text-muted"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pull-right text-muted"></span>
        </td>
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The idea is correct and it should work as long as you `set` the `objectId` via the ember object setters. Also try to use `get('objectId')` on a specific object/instance of `App.Session`. If you post a working example (e.g. jsfiddle.net, emberjs.jsbin.com) you will get complete answers.

Comment: Can you show how is declared the App.Store, and how do you change the  `objectId` value?